# How to rotate a GameObject more than once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

trying to use suggested option have an error vector3 right   is not in its definition 
line transform.Rotate(Vector3.Right

thank you in advance

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ForwardBack : MonoBehaviour {
    // speed variable
    public float speed;


    public KeyCode pressLeft;
    public KeyCode pressRight;
    public float rotationSpeed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        speed = 1f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        transform.Translate(0f, speed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical") *     Time.deltaTime,0f);

         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.Right * rotationSpeed *    Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.Left * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) it's `transform.eulerAngles`.  but in your case (2) you simply want `.Rotate`, not `.eulerAngles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few inefficiencies in your code. You should not call `GetComponent<>()` in the `Update` loop. Instead store a referece to it using the `Start` function and use that in the `Update` loop:

```
public class ForwardBack : MonoBehaviour 
{

    private Transform thisTransform = null;

    void Start () 
    {
        // Get refrence
        thisTransform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        //Use refrence.
        thisTransform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Note: You might realise that every child of `MonoBehaviour` inherits the `transform` property which will look up a reference to the `Transform` component. Using this is inefficient. You should get your own reference like I have shown here.

Edit:As noted by @JoeBlow the `transform` property *may* be fine to use. There is nothing mentioned about how it returns the `Transform` component in the Unity docs. I have read that it is just a wrapper for `GetComponent` though from a few different sources. Use at your own discretion.

Secondly, don't use eulerAngles to rotate. It even says so in the [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html).

> Only use this variable to read and set the angles to absolute values. Don't increment them, as it will fail when the angle exceeds 360 degrees. Use Transform.Rotate instead.

It looks like you're not even incrementing the angle, just setting it to `new Vector3(0, 0, -90)` anyways which means even if you did do this it will just be set to that value rather than slowly increasing.

The docs for `eulerAngles` also lead you to what you should be using which is [Transform.Rotate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html).To get this to work you will have to change the input method to `Input.GetKey`rather than `Input.GetKeyDown` but this has already been mentioned in one of the other answers. Then you can rotate around your desired axis. Remember to use `Time.deltaTime` to scale the value so as it rotates at the same speed no matter what framerate you have. Your code for rotation might look something like this:

```
public class ForwardBack : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float roatationSpeed;
    private Transform thisTransform = null;

    void Start () 
    {
        thisTransform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)
        {
             thisTransform.Rotate(Vector3.right * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)
        {
             thisTransform.Rotate(Vector3.left * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  First attempt in programming in unity.  Watched a few youtube videos must have confused myself.  Thank you again will try later

Comment: @KevinCranfield That's cool man, everyone starts somewhere. Be careful with YouTube videos though it's easy to pick up some bad habits. If this, or any other answer to your questions, is the answer you were looking for then remember to accept it too!

Comment: hey @gjttt1  Are you absolutely sure that .transform uses GetComponent each time?  I believe that is **not** the case.  Don't forget, a Transform is an inherent property of a GameObject; it's not a component which is added.  It's just a variable and .transform accesses it.  As you know in the "old days" Unity had some "convenience 'properties'" which stupidly just use GetComponent, they were just shorthand for writing GetComponent.  But .transform is not of that nature, as I understand it.

Comment: @JoeBlow hmm, good point. I suppose as unity evolves these things might be made more efficient. I  have read a few times from a few different sources that it is just a wrapper for `GetComponent` but this might have changed. I'll update the answer to say that it may be ok to use. I personally just tend to get the reference my self to be on the safe side as nothing is mentioned about how the transform property actually returns the Transform in the unity docs.

Comment: You know, I'm almost certain it's just literally the variable ".transform".  (It's worth remembering that after all, a GameObject ... *is* ... a "Transform"! That's all it is. There's nothing else that makes-up a "game object" other than that it has the quaternions that place it in the scene and those are twisted each frame, i.e., "a Transform".  Anyways one can look in the code these days - but i'm too lazy  :)  In any event yes, I agree it would be good if this was absolutely clarified in the doco.  Cheers

Comment: Hi i have tried your suggestion and getting error vector3 does not contain a definition for right..

Comment: I would suggest to use `Input.GetAxis` or `Input.GetButton` to be a bit more flexible about which key is used.

Comment: oops my bad. Lower case 'r' is required!

Comment: `Vector3.right` with upper case for Vector3 and lower case for right.

Comment: @KevinCranfield please check the suggestion of changing the `Vector3.right`. The word `right` needs to be lower case! Same with `left` obviously

Comment: Thank you working just rotating on the wrong axis i should be able to figure that out.

Comment: I think i can any way

Comment: try `Vector3.up` and `Vector3.down`. There are many different unit vectors that you can use. See [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html)

Comment: Thank you all working had to use forward and back awesome

Comment: @gjttt1 and whoever is interested aswell. i found this very interesting and raced my horses. for a thousand times i was adding something to transfrom position. first i used transform from monobehavior, took about 4.6ms, second i used a cached reference 1.7ms and lastly i querried GetComponent each time, guess what - 2.4ms (!), still twice as fast as .transform - but it was on an empty, i maybe should have tested it with 6-7 components attached to have a more realistic value. anyway, this clearly shows, caching is vastly superior - but its probably not the biggest culprit either.

Comment: @yes that's amazing! really strange that `GetComponent` is faster that `.transform`. I wonder what on earth unity is doing under the hood when calling `.transform`. Thanks for the info man, it's priceless!

Comment: @gjttt1 i made a mistake, the above values are too high by the order of a magnitude (its given in seconds, too many zeros ^^) anyway, now i added a couple of colliders, an audio source, and an animator and i get a whole different results for ANY verison. this is very strange. .transform now takes ~1.2ms, cached 0.9ms and getcomponent 1.1ms. why is the cached version getting slower aswell? edit: well maybe because of the colldiers attached, in the end i set a position.

Comment: @yes super strange, maybe ask as a question if anyone has any insight into this?

Answer (score 2):

Try `Input.GetKey` instead of `Input.GetKeyDown`

`Input.GetKeyDown` detects if a button is pressed, whereas `Input.GetKey` checks for a continuous press. I imagine that is why your cylinder is only turning once.